# MySQL server has gone away - Zend

Tags: php, mysql, soap, zend-framework

I have very strange problem. I'm working on shop based on zend framework. I'm creating integration with some auction service (allegro.pl). I need to download via soap all items. After my function finish job I get "MySQL server has gone away".

Here is my code:

```
private function getProducts()
    {
        $items = [];
        $filterOptions = /* doesn't matter for this question */;
        $allegroItems = $this->allegro->getCore()->doGetItemsList(0, 1, $filterOptions, 3, null);

        $itemsCount = $allegroItems->itemsCount;
        $perPage = 1000;
        $maxPage = ceil(round($itemsCount, 0) / $perPage);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $maxPage; $i++) {
            $allegroItems = $this->allegro->getCore()->doGetItemsList($perPage * $i, $perPage, $filterOptions, 3, null)->itemsList->item;

            if (!is_array($allegroItems)) {
                $allegroItems = [$allegroItems];
            }

            foreach ($allegroItems as $item) {
                $items[(string)$item->itemId] = $item;
            }
        }

        return $items;
    }
```

There are ~3000 items currently. I get error when I download over 2500-3000 items (didn't calculate exact number). It doesn't matter if I set $perPage to 1, 100 or 1000. It doesn't depend on execution time - I can set sleep(100) and download 1000 products with no error. Just before last line of this function I can call any DB query with no problems but then, when framework's built in function tries to update tasks table I get error.

Error seems to depend on nothing... Not execution time (time is ~30 sec and it's working fine with sleep(100)), not memory limit (I can unset variables each loop or set memory limit to 1GB, didn't help), not execution time of soap functions (downloading 2000 items one by one works fine although it takes few minutes). And the most strange for me - db queries are working inside that function just before the last line like I said.

I'm not using clear zend framework but "shoper" which is based on zend.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to close  the current connection to mysql (during this operation) and re-open it when you need it ? Also have a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with BLOB data. Increasing max_allowed_packet solved it. However I have no idea what was in that BLOB and how my function could affect it because I wrote it as completely independent function :-)